# Hadoop is not showing my job in the job tracker even though it is running

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-yarn

**Problem:** When I submit a job to my hadoop 2.2.0 cluster it doesn't show up in the job tracker **but the job completes successfully.** By this I can see the output and it is running correctly and prints output as it is running.

I have tried muliple options but the  job tracker is not seeing the job. If I run a streaming job using the 2.2.0 hadoop it shows up in the task tracker but when I submit it via the hadoop-client api it does not show up in the job tracker. I am looking at the ui interface on port 8088 to verify the job

**Environment**
OSX Mavericks, Java 1.6, Hadoop 2.2.0 single node cluster, Tomcat 7.0.47

**Code**

```
    try {
        configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000");
        configuration.set("mapred.jobtracker.address", "localhost:9001");

        Job job = createJob(configuration);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to execute job", e);
    }

    return null;
```

**etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>localhost:9001</value>
    </property> 
</configuration>
```

**etc/hadoop/core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
     <property>
       <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
       <value>/tmp/hadoop-${user.name}</value>
       <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>

    <property> 
      <name>fs.default.name</name> 
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value> 
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The resolution to the issue was to configure the job with the extra configuration options for yarn. I made int incorrect assumption that the java hadoop-client api would use the configuration options from the configuration directory. I was able to diagnose the problem by turning on verbose logging using log4j.properties for my unit tests. It showed that the jobs were running local and not being submitted to the yarn resource manager. With a little bit of trial and error I was able to configure the job and have it submitted to the yarn resource manager.

**Code**

```
    try {
        configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000");
        configuration.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "localhost:54311");
        configuration.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
        configuration.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "localhost:8032");

        Job job = createJob(configuration);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to execute job", e);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that `mapreduce.job.tracker` is a real Hadoop property.

Comment: @amoe, it was in 1.x.. Replaced by `mapreduce.jobtracker.address` in the 2.x

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe, not trying to be pedantic, but `mapreduce.job.tracker` doesn't seem to exist at all.  Try putting it into google (in quotes).

Comment: My bad, seems my brain had dropped the `uce` while reading your comment

Comment: I fixed it, I am sure it was a mistype from me. The reason it worked is probably because I was reading Configurations in from an xml config file also.

Comment: if you are using webhdfs also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637326/accessing-hdfs-remotedly

Answer (score 4):

I see that you are using Hadoop 2.2.0. Are you using MRv1 or MRv2? The daemons are different for MRv2 (YARN). There is no JobTracker for MRv2, though you may see a placeholder page for the JobTracker UI.

The ResourceManager web UI should display your submitted jobs. The default web URL for the ResourceManager is http://<*ResourcemanagerHost*>:8088

Replace ResourceManagerHost with the IP address of the node where the Resource Manager is running.

You can read more about the YARN architecture at [Apache Hadoop YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.2.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)

Comment: I am using the mrv2 api. I am also checking the resource manager at http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps/SUBMITTED. This is where I do not see my job being submitted with the mrv2 api but if I submit a simple streaming job it shows up in the submitted apps. I guess the question is in MRv2 how do I view my jobs, job history. I am off to read the yarn docs. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: i have the same issue, did you find your issue's resolution ? @ChrisHinshaw

Comment: @Raghav if you read my answer it tells you exactly what happened. Check the answer that I posted.