# Applications not shown in yarn UI when running mapreduce hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am using `Hadoop2.2`. I see that my jobs are completed with success. I can browse the filesystem to find the output. However, when I browse `http://NNode:8088/cluster/apps`, I am unable to see any applications that have been completed so far ( I ran 3 wordcount jobs, but none of it is seen here).

Are there any configurations that need to be taken into account?

[image]

Here is the `yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>NNode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
<!--
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
-->
```

Here is `mapred-site.xml`:

```
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
```

I have job history server running too:

```
jps
4422 NameNode
5452 Jps
4695 SecondaryNameNode
4924 ResourceManager
72802 Jps
5369 JobHistoryServer
```

Comment: Try to check hadoop logs files. you might find warnings or errors there. But it seems that your datanode is down

Comment: @eliasah: The datanode is running fine. I did not show `jps` on datanode. what I showed above is namenode(master). The datanode runs fine and even my jobs are finished.

Comment: @brainstorm Can you post the entire output of a wordcount job?  All of it.

Comment: And by output, I mean what you get in the terminal

Comment: @climbage: Thanks for helping out. Two things I observed, one is I need to start yarn in my namenode. Then it seems to work. If I do `start-yarn.sh` in my client, it does not start resourcemanager. I dont know why. Secondly, Although I see my job being listed in application window, I cannot find information about number of mappers and reducers etc. In hadoop1, it was easy to find them in 50030 port I guess. Do you know how to get that info, in hadoop2 on the UI

Answer (score 0):

After applications are completed, their responsibility might be moved to `Job History Server`. So check `Job History Server` URL. It normally listen on port `19888`. E.g.

`http://<job_history_server_address>:19888/jobhistory`

Log directories and log retain durations are configurable in `yarn-site.xml`. With `YARN`, even one can aggregate logs to a single (configurable) location.

Sometimes, even though application is listed, logs are not available (I am not sure if its due to some bug in `YARN`). However, almost each time I was able to get the logs using command line:

> yarn logs -applicationId the_application_id

Athough there are multiple options. Use help for details:

> yarn logs --help

Answer (score 0):

you can refer [Hadoop is not showing my job in the job tracker even though it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345022/hadoop-is-not-showing-my-job-in-the-job-tracker-even-though-it-is-running)

```
                    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://master:9000");
                    conf.set("mapreduce.jobtracker.address", "master:54311");
                    conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
                    conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "master:8032");
```

I tested in my cluster. It works!