# unable to run map reduce using python in Hadoop?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I have written mapper and reducer in python for word count program that works fine.
Here is a sample:

```
echo "hello hello world here hello here world here hello" | wordmapper.py | sort -k1,1 | wordreducer.py 
hello   4
here    3
world   2
```

Now when i try to submit a hadoop job for a large file, I get errors

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/sources/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file wordmapper.py -mapper wordmapper.py  -file wordreducer.py -reducer wordreducer.py -input /data/1jrl.pdb -output /output/py_jrl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: share.hadoop.tools.sources.hadoop-streaming-2.2.0-test-sources.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

I removed changed the commandline to the following (removed wild card from above);

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/sources/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0-sources.jar -file wordmapper.py -mapper wordmapper.py  -file wordreducer.py -reducer wordreducer.py -input /data/1jrl.pdb -output /output/py_jrl
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -file
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

why I get these errors and how to fix this?
I use `hadoop2.` Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well at least one of your issues is that you are using the `-sources.jar` which is just `.java` files and can't be executed.

Try using this instead...

```
share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0.jar
```

And if that doesn't exist, look for a `hadoop-streaming*.jar` that doesn't have `-sources` in the file name.

Comment: This worked great. Do you know where I can look for java files (source code)  for the classes in share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar

Comment: Go to the [Hadoop 2.2 Apache download page](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.2.0/) and download `hadoop-2.2.0-src.tar.gz`

Comment: sorry this could be stupid question. should I have to download entire hadoop-src tar to get the source code for examples?

Comment: You may have luck finding the 2.2 source for mapreduce examples, but I've always just downloaded the entire source so I can see everything.