# Hadoop ResourceManager not show any job's record

Tags: hadoop

I install Hadoop MultiNode cluster based on this link http://pingax.com/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-cluster-setup/

then I try to run wordcount example in my environment, but when I access to Resource Manager http://HadoopMaster:8088 to see the job's details, no records show in UI.

I also search this problem, one guy give the solution like that [Hadoop is not showing my job in the job tracker even though it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21345022/hadoop-is-not-showing-my-job-in-the-job-tracker-even-though-it-is-running?lq=1) but in my case, I'm just running hadoop's example, in which wordcount also didn't add any extra configuration for yarn.

Anyone has install successfully Hadoop2 Muiltinode and Hadoop web UI works correctly can help me about this issue or can give a link to install correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you got the output of word-count job?

Comment: Yes, I got the output of the map. I just found out the cause. In the mapred-site.xml instead of <name>mapred.framework.name</name> as tutorial given, replace it by <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>, then it worked.